# How to copy text to clipboard using a certain charset

Tags: powershell, batch-file, encoding, character-encoding

I've been trying to make a program using a combination of batch files and [Quick Macros](http://www.quickmacros.com/) that automatically adds diacritic to a piece of text in my native language (Czech).
I've got everything working;

- The user selects text on screen
- presses a key board shortcut
- which copies the text to a file
- a POST request containing the text is then sent to the [server](https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/cz_accent/) (using a batch script)
- the response is stored in the response file
- the same batch script trims the response file to only get the
  fixed text
- and stores it in another file

and here is where I run into problems. Czech diacritic uses the ISO-8859-2 charset, but copying the file content gets ANSI encoding, breaking the accented characters when it is subsequently pasted to replace the user's original selected text.
At the moment I get around this by having QM open an instance of Notepad++, manually going through the menus to change the charset, then selecting and copying the text, and closing Notepad++.
As you can see this is VERY inelegant, resulting in a window popping up on my screen every time I run the script, waiting for which accounts for about 80% of the total runtime.

Does anyone know how I can get text from a text file into the clipboard using a certain charset? Preferably with batch or powershell? (I know this works if it is copied while already being displayed in the correct charset, so I imagine it is somehow possible).

All my code:
**QM** *triggered by keyboard shortcut* (bit messy-looking but every line is commented)

```
/create variable 's' and copy current selection to it
str s.getsel;
/if nothing was selected, the program ends
if (empty(s))
    end
/remember which window the selection is from
int orWin = win
/create "params.txt" from content of 's'
s.setfile("D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\params.txt");
/wait until "params.txt" is created (yes, this is the right way to do it)
rep
    if(FileExists("D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\params.txt")) break
/run "endline_purge.bat" minimised
run "D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\endline_purge_min";
/wait for "endling_purge.bat" to close (any command window being destroyed triggers this)
wait -1 WD win("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");
/copy new content of "params.txt" to variabel 's'
s.getfile("D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\params.txt");
/remove "params.txt"
del- "D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\params.txt";
/run "request.bat" minimised, passing 's' as arguments
run "D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\request_min" s;
/wait for "request.bat" to close
wait -1 WD win("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");
/remove "response.html"
del- "D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\response.html"
/open "output.txt" (created by "request.bat") in Notepad++
run "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\output.txt"
/wait for Notepad++ to open
wait -1 WA win("D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\output.txt - Notepad++" "Notepad++")
/use shortcut keys to select ISO-8859-2 charset
'An cY eY
/if a dialog opens, confirm it (error occurs if it is not open)
act(win("Save Current Modification"))
err goto search_cont
'Y
 search_cont
/select all
'Ca
/copy selection to 's'
s.getsel
/close Notepad++
clo
/delete "output.txt"
del- "D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\output.txt"
/restore the original window where selection is active
act(orWin)
/trim trailing endline from 's' (13=CR 10=NL)
str CRNL.format("%c%c", 13 10)
s.rtrim(CRNL)
/paste content of 's' (into the active selection, replacing it)
'(s)
```

**endline_purge.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (params.txt) do set "line=!line!\n%%a"
echo !line:~2!>params.txt
```

**request.bat** (also trims out unwanted content from the html response)

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\cURL\curl.exe" --data "text=%*" https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/cz_accent/ > D:\AppData\Local\CZaccent\response.html
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set content=
for /f "delims=" %%i in (response.html) do set content=!content! %%i
set content=!content:~391,-993!
echo !content:^<p^> =^

! > output.txt
```

Comment: The command to __change codepage__ is `chcp`. You can run `chcp` without any parameter in a command prompt window to get displayed which code page is defined by default on your computer for your user account according to configured region. The usage of `chcp 1250` at top of your batch file might be the right command for your task.

Comment: I tried adding chcp 852 (slavic) but the console still outputs the wrong charset into the clipboard. Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: turns out its chcp 28592 for iso-8859-2! Thanks so much!

Comment: I thought you would prefer code page [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) as this code page is used by Windows GUI applications with having Czech selected as region. But it is of course also possible to use [ISO/IEC 8859-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2).

Answer (score 0):

```
chcp 28592
```

This command makes `cmd.exe` display (and copy) text in ISO-8859-2, showing the accented characters correctly.